# How to prevent redirect when using the term "page" in query string?

Tags: permalinks, query

I want to use the query string '?page=1' for pagination of some posts but whenever I do, Wordpress intercepts it and redirects to a post page with that ID.

How can I prevent this happening?

I am using a custom permalink structure "/blog/%postname%/"

Comment: `page` is a keyword for WP - why don't you name your pagination parameter differently?

Comment: I thought about that but hit a wall trying to think of other words that make sense. Is it a keyword for the built in pagination of Wordpress?

Comment: No, that'd be `paged`, but it's a keyword for WP's parameters. It'll usually add a rewrite rule like `'(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$1&page=$2'`. Use another name, maybe `startat` or `showpage`.

Comment: Why don't you just use native in-post pagination?